# How do i retrieve customer transaction from paystack and insert into my database?

Tags: php, mysql, json, curl

Here is the code in controller:

```
function verify_transaction(){
    $db = $this->GetModel();
    $tablename = $this->tablename;
    
    
    $ref = $_GET['reference'];
    if($ref = ""){
        header("Location:javascript://history.go(-1)");
    }
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.paystack.co/transaction/verify/:reference",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "Authorization: Bearer sk_test_c3197c645471e98ea33a6dd2e010e7ade7fe1aee",
      "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    ),
  ));
  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $err = curl_error($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
  if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
  } else {
    //echo $response;
    $result = json_decode($response);
  }
  if($result->data->status == 'success'){
    $status = $result->data->status;
    $reference = $result->data->reference;
    $amount = $result->data->amount;
    $fname = $result->data->customer->first_name;
    $lname = $result->data->customer->last_name;
    $fullname = $lname.' '.$fname;
    $cus_email = $result->data->customer->email;
    $date_time = date('m/d/y h:i:s a',time());
    
    $table_data = array(
    "fullname" => $fullname,
    "amount" => $amount,
    "status" => $status,
    "reference" => $reference,
    "date_paid" => $date_time,
    "email" => $cus_email
    );
    $rec_id = $this->rec_id=$db->insert($tablename, $table_data);
    if($rec_id){
        header("Location: successful.php?status=success");
        exit;
    }
    else{
    $this->set_page_error();
    }
  }
    
}
```

Here is the error:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$data in C:\wamp64\www\hms\app\controllers\PaymentsController.php on line 359

> Notice: Trying to get property 'status' of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\hms\app\controllers\PaymentsController.php on line 359

Comment: It's trying to tell you that `$result` doesn't have a `data` property. Use `var_dump($result)` to find out the actual structure of the response.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to check for the status of an object that does not exist. Try doing the check within  your else block as follows:

```
if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
  } else {
    //echo $response;
    $result = json_decode($response);

  //Now that you have result, you can check for the status now
  
   if($result->data->status == 'success'){

    $status = $result->data->status;

    ........
}
```